# In Google data studio I have added input box control and I want to use it as a Word Filter

Tags: looker-studio

I have a data that looks like this which has more than 500k Choices:

| Country | Choice |
| --- | --- |
| Brazil | Rock |
| Brazil | Rock |
| Brazil | Paper |
| Peru | Scissors |
| Peru | Scissors |
| Peru | Rock |
| Cuba | Paper |

What I want is to control the data based on Input value. Let's say I add the input "rock", I want the table to remove all the rows having rock in choice column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something along these lines should work out.

1. create a parameter ([SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1jZh.png))
2. Add a input box with the above created parameter as 'control field'.
3. Add a new field with the following calculated formula ([SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmc2J.png))

`CASE WHEN Choice=Parameter_Choice THEN '' ELSE Choice END`

4. Add a filter to the table to filter out the '' from the calculated field in step 3  ([SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuUcB.png))

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much :) It worked. However, if we want multiple options in Parameter choice, what we will do? For example, data has multiple terms. I want to exlclude paper, rock both by adding in input term. Is it possible?

Comment: a simple way is to change the calculated formula to REGEXP_MATCH as shown here (https://i.imgur.com/y5SIHHP.png) and in the input box enter 'Rock|Paper'